# What could be causing differential signal drift?

Tags: differential

I looking at a differential signal on a scope, and I see that while the signal should be exactly equal and opposite the values are slowly drifting slightly.

The quantity I'm looking at is the areas of the positive and negative pulses, the should be equal and opposite but they are not. Further, I want them to agree within 5%, but watching on the oscilloscope I see that they slowly drift in and out of this tolerance.

The circuit in question is a single-ended signal from a signal generator going through a single winding on the primary of a toroid, the secondary of the toroid is 8 turns into a twinax cable, which I have broken out to two coaxial cables into two channels of an oscilloscope.

[image]

Comment: Try heating up different parts of your system one by one. The signal source, the transmission path, the toroid, the scope probes, etc. Whichever one causes the biggest change is probably your (main) culprit.

Comment: Is the secondary connected only to the two scope channels, and nothing else?  Try some 10K or at least 100K resistors from each side to the BNC grounds, the megaohm impedance of the scope is pretty large making you susceptible to stray pretty much anything showing up as a common-mode offset.

Comment: Also when you say "twinax" do you mean that there's actually no electrical connection between the channels, but rather two one-ended wires?

Comment: @ThePhoton so you think its a thermal issue? Yeah that could be an interesting test

Comment: @ChrisStratton check the image I uploaded for a quick drawing of the circuit

Comment: @ChrisStratton so it sounds like you think I should terminate the coax as well, 10k or 100k from the signal to ground on each leg?

Comment: Your image link is messed up.  Also, there is a built-in schematic editor you can use while you edit your post.

Comment: I think if what you care about is a differential AC component (which is presumably the case with a transformer secondary) then you should do something to establish a deterministic DC bias, presumably to ground.  So yes, you want some resistors.  I can only guess at the suitable value.

Comment: @kefffin, whenever something drifts over a period of a few seconds or minutes, I suspect a thermal effect.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have a ground reference. The scope measures relative to ground.

What is the frequency of the signal?

It could be beating with noise pickup (such as 50/60Hz) because you don't have  aground reference.

You could split the 215 ohm resistor (why 215 ohm?) into two 107.5 Ohm resistors with the junction connected to ground. That would refer the two signals to ground but still terminate the differential signal.